# Android 10 and no internet wifi

Tags: wi-fi, internet, android-10

I've been working on developing an android app for some time now that is meant to communicate with an embedded device.

The embedded device acts as its own Wireless Access point, and has no internet connection. Since having updated a couple of android devices (A pixel 2 and a pixel 3a) that we were using for testing to Android 10, we've noticed that the device will switch off of the WIFI without internet to a different profile that has internet. This happens somewhere between 30 seconds and 5 minutes after having connected to the embedded device. (I also tested this on a generic router, with the same outcome.)

Is there anyway to prevent this behavior?

Comment: In the general Wifi settings of Android 10 there is a "Network rating provider" setting. Have you tried to change the rating provider to "None"? Assuming that a network without Internet gets a lower rating this could explain the automatic Wifi switching.

Comment: Yhea, that was set to None.
I also tried disabling Turn on Wi-Fi automatically, everything under Wi-Fi control, and Wi-Fi scanning. None of that changed the behavior I was seeing.

Comment: Have you been able to solve this problem? I am seeing the same on a Pixel 3a device with Android 10.

Comment: Not exactly, it turns out it was a bug in Android. I had filed a bug report back in October regarding this. As of May 13, one of marked the issue as fixed and google stated that the fix will be available in a future build.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141903691